# Responsive 50% 2 column html/css

Tags: html, css

I suspect that what I want to achieve might not be possible with plain HTML/CSS, but here goes anyway. I would like a 2 column layout which wraps nicely on mobile devices. Each column to take up 50% of the container width if there is room, but 100% of the container width if they wrap.

Here is some example markup:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" >
<head>
    <title>Responsive 2 col</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .colcontainer
        {
            width: auto;
            overflow:hidden;
            border: solid 1px red;
        }
        .leftcol
        {
            width: 49%;
            float: left;
            margin-right:10px;
            border: solid 1px blue;
        }
        .rightcol
        {
            width: 49%;
            float: left;
            border: solid 1px green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="colcontainer">
        <div class="leftcol">
            Here is a paragraph which has enough text to cause it to take up a fair amount of width if left to its own devices.
        </div>
        <div class="rightcol">
            A smaller paragraph.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This looks OK but when you squash the browser width to make the divs wrap, they still only take up 50% of the container width each. By removing the width:49%, it wraps nicely and fills the available width but the columns are no longer evenly split when not wrapped. Is there any way of making them fill the available width when wrapped, but take up 50% of the available width when not wrapped?

Comment: Are there any other CSS rules that apply, which are not shown here? Also, why are you styling your elements in the markup? are you using media queries? Also, use box-sizing: border-box

Comment: I put the CSS in the page purely for the sake of making a simple example. In reality the CSS is in a separate file. There are no other relevant styling rules - the example above shows the problem. I was hoping to avoid using separate stylesheets for different devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need multiple things here, first of all you are making a responsive grid, so whenever you make responsive things, make sure you use the CSS snippet below

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This will change the box model behavior and will count the `padding` and `border` inside the box instead of outside..

Secondly, if you want to wrap the elements, you can declare break points using `@media` queries, this way they won't be squished.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/x9A4s/) *(Resize the window and see the effect)*